# How to store a state in @ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I was making a project, there I have called two different standalone components which are declared inside two different ng-containers(container-1,container-2;both are standalone components). Now, suppose Container-1 has a form and on clicking 'next' button in the container-1 we move to the next page where Container-2 loads but when I again try to move back to Container-1 from container-2 the form data in container-1 resets. I don't want to loose that data, how can I retreive that data again?

this is the app.action.ts file:

```
  import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
  import { Step } from './main';

   export const setCurrentStep = createAction(
     '[App] Set Current Step',
     props<{ step: Step }>()
   );
```

this is what I did in the reducer file:

```
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { setCurrentStep } from './app.actions';
import { Step } from './main';

export interface AppState {
  currentStep: Step;
}

export const initialState: AppState = {
  currentStep: 1,
};

export const appReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(setCurrentStep, (state, { step }) => ({
    ...state,
    currentStep: step,
  }))
);
```

This is the shared-service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from './app.state';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { setCurrentStep } from './app.actions';
import { Step } from './main';

@Injectable()
export class SharedServiceService {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  setCurrentStep(step: Step) {
    this.store.dispatch(setCurrentStep({ step }));
    console.log('setCurrentStep =>', this.store);
  }

  getCurrentStep(): Observable<Step> {
    return this.store.pipe(select('step'));
  }
}
```

This is the stackblitz [link of the project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2p3wju?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fcomp-2%2Fcomp-2.component.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2Fcomp-1%2Fcomp-1.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fcomponents%2Fcomp-1%2Fcomp-1.component.html,src%2Fcomponents%2Fcomp-2%2Fcomp-2.component.html,src%2Fshared-service.service.ts,src%2Fapp.state.ts,src%2Fapp.actions.ts,src%2Fapp.reducer.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

This is the first time I am using ngrx/store,so maybe I missed something here. Can somebody help?

Comment: I am sorry but you have to investigate solutions before asking for help on stackoverflow. Things you are asking are already well documented on ngrx site (https://ngrx.io/guide/store). On top of that your stackblitz project is broken and throws an error.

Comment: `localStorage`...